# How do I handle the repetitive starting of multiple threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Until now, when using threads, I've always started them right away in my program and then made them wait on notification from a main control thread.

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
for(int i = 0; i != thread_count; ++i) {
    threads.push_back(std::thread(&MyClass::myfunction, this));
}

/* some time later in the code */
for(auto& t : threads) {
    t.join();
}
```

Now I want to start threads on demand from a function run by my control thread, but I'm unsure how to handle the thread objects and their joining.

The following would push a new thread object onto the vector for each call, which strikes me as not ideal:

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
while(accumulating_data) {
    if(buffer_full) {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(&MyClass::myfunction, this));
    }
}
```

Having the vector hold no more than the maximum number on consecutively running threads seems preferable. I also don't know how to join the threads here without blocking the control thread.

If I do something like this instead:

```
// dummy code, in my real code I have a queue of idle IDs
std::vector<std::thread> threads(thread_count);
while(accumulating_data) {
    if(buffer_full) {
        threads[thread_id] = std::thread(&MyClass::myfunction, this);
        if(++thread_id == thread_count) { thread_id = 0; }
    }
}
```

...I quickly crash, probably because I haven't joined or am reassigning to a vector element that already contains a std::thread object.

Any hints on how I can accomplish my goal of starting threads on demand, instead of having them wait?

**Update:**

I managed to get the code to run without crashing by introducing a `std::thread.joinable()` check. I'm still open to opinions on how to handle this more elegantly, <del>so I won't make it the answer to my own question:</del>

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads(thread_count);
while(accumulating_data) {
    if(buffer_full) {
        if(threads[thread_id].joinable()) {
            threads[thread_id].join(); }
        }
        threads[thread_id] = std::thread(&MyClass::myfunction, this);
        if(++thread_id == thread_count) { thread_id = 0; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just make a thread only when you need one rather than trying to do whatever it is you are trying to do?

Comment: You might be looking for boost::thread_group.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames I start the threads to do parallel processing. The difference here would be that instead of starting i.e. 8 threads at once and have them wait for data, I spawn a thread _when data is ready_, while ensuring that no more than 7 have already been spawned.

Comment: @Adrian do you really need to create a joinable thread? Is creating a detached thread reasonable for your code?

Comment: @alvits Unfortunately yes. The main thread parses an xml file into buffers while (newly spawned) threads process those buffers. Once all processing has finished, the main thread proceeds to handle the data. I updated my question, I think i got it working now.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer. I'll uptick it.

Comment: @alvits Ok then, so be it.

Comment: It looks like [async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) and [future](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) is the library feature you really need.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the code to run without crashing by introducing a `std::thread.joinable()` check. I'm still open to opinions on how to handle this more elegantly :)

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads(thread_count);
while(accumulating_data) {
    if(buffer_full) {
        /* the following check returns false prior to an assignment */
        if(threads[thread_id].joinable()) {
            threads[thread_id].join(); }
        }
        threads[thread_id] = std::thread(&MyClass::myfunction, this);
        if(++thread_id == thread_count) { thread_id = 0; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want..

```
#include <thread>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

class ThreadGroup
{
    private:
        std::uint32_t max_threads;
        std::vector<std::tuple<std::thread::native_handle_type, std::thread, bool*>> data;

    public:
        ThreadGroup() : max_threads(std::thread::hardware_concurrency()), data(max_threads) {}
        ThreadGroup(std::uint32_t max_threads) : max_threads(max_threads), data(max_threads) {}
        ~ThreadGroup();

        template<class Function, class... Args>
        std::thread::native_handle_type insert(bool &terminate, Function&& f, Args&&... args);
        bool remove(std::thread::native_handle_type id);
};

ThreadGroup::~ThreadGroup()
{
    for (auto &it : data)
    {
        if (std::get<0>(it))
        {
            if (!*std::get<2>(it))
            {
                std::get<1>(it).detach();
                continue;
            }

            std::get<1>(it).join();
        }
    }
}

template<class Function, class... Args>
std::thread::native_handle_type ThreadGroup::insert(bool &terminate, Function&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (auto &it : data)
    {
        if (std::get<0>(it) == 0)
        {
            auto &&t = std::thread(std::forward<Function>(f), std::forward(args)...);
            auto &&tup = std::make_tuple(t.native_handle(), std::forward<std::thread>(t), &terminate);
            data[i] = std::move(tup);
            return std::get<0>(data[i]);
        }
        ++i;
    }
    throw std::length_error("Maximum thread limit reached.");
}

bool ThreadGroup::remove(std::thread::native_handle_type id)
{
    for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (std::get<0>(*it) == id)
        {
            if (std::get<1>(*it).joinable() && *std::get<2>(*it))
            {
                std::get<1>(*it).join();
                std::get<0>(*it) = 0;
                std::get<2>(*it) = nullptr;
                //data.erase(it);
                return true;
            }
            std::get<1>(*it).detach();
            std::get<0>(*it) = 0;
            std::get<2>(*it) = nullptr;
            //data.erase(it);
            return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then I used it like:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

bool terminate1 = false, terminate2 = false, terminate3 = false, terminate4 = false, terminate5 = false;

void func1()
{
    while(!terminate1)
    {
        std::cout<<"T1 ";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

void func2()
{
    while(!terminate2)
    {
        std::cout<<"T2 ";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

void func3()
{
    while(!terminate3)
    {
        std::cout<<"T3 ";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

void func4()
{
    while(!terminate4)
    {
        std::cout<<"T4 ";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

void func5()
{
    while(!terminate5)
    {
        std::cout<<"T5 ";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

int main()
{
    ThreadGroup group;
    auto id1 = group.insert(terminate1, func1);
    auto id2 = group.insert(terminate2, func2);
    auto id3 = group.insert(terminate3, func3);
    auto id4 = group.insert(terminate4, func4);

    try
    {
        auto id5 = group.insert(terminate5, func5); //limit in my case is 4. inserting 5 will throw max limit exception..
    }
    catch(std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cout<<"\n\n"<<e.what()<<"\n\n";
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
    terminate1 = true;  //allow the thread to join..
    group.remove(id1);  //joins if the thread is finished..

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
    group.remove(id2);  //remove another thread (detaches if the thread isn't finished)..

    auto id5 = group.insert(terminate5, func5); //insert a new thread in any of the old slots..
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
}
```